# Displaying MySQL results from a relation of a relation

Tags: php, mysql

If I have three tables, and I'm trying to loop through all posts:

```
posts: post_id, post_title, post_content
tag_relations: post_id, tag_id
tags: tag_ig, tag_name
```

If each post will have multiple tags, how would I display each tag for each post?

As in, how would I have to setup my SQL query, and how would I print the results? Would it be easier just to use multiple queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL provides the useful [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function, which you may want to use as follows:

```
SELECT    p.post_id, p.post_title, GROUP_CONCAT(tag_name SEPARATOR ', ') tags
FROM      posts p
JOIN      tag_relations tr ON (tr.post_id = p.post_id)
JOIN      tags t ON (t.tag_id = tr.tag_id)
GROUP BY  p.post_id;
```

Test case:

```
CREATE TABLE posts (post_id int, post_title varchar(50));
CREATE TABLE tags (tag_id int, tag_name varchar(50));
CREATE TABLE tag_relations (post_id int, tag_id int);

INSERT INTO posts VALUES (1, 'post 1');
INSERT INTO posts VALUES (2, 'post 2');
INSERT INTO posts VALUES (3, 'post 3');

INSERT INTO tags VALUES (1, 'mysql');
INSERT INTO tags VALUES (2, 'sql');
INSERT INTO tags VALUES (3, 'javascript');
INSERT INTO tags VALUES (4, 'python');

INSERT INTO tag_relations VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO tag_relations VALUES (1, 2);
INSERT INTO tag_relations VALUES (2, 3);
INSERT INTO tag_relations VALUES (3, 2);
INSERT INTO tag_relations VALUES (3, 4);
```

Result:

```
+---------+------------+-------------+
| post_id | post_title | tags        |
+---------+------------+-------------+
|       1 | post 1     | mysql, sql  |
|       2 | post 2     | javascript  |
|       3 | post 3     | sql, python |
+---------+------------+-------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

As [@Alfonso de la Osa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/252675/alfonso-de-la-osa) noted in a comment below, you can use [left outer joins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Left_outer_join) instead of [inner joins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Inner_join) to get back posts without any tags.

Comment: with left joins if you want to retrieve the posts without tags too

Comment: @Alfonso: Updated my answer with a note on that.